# TestNG reporting issues due to multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have a testNG framework integrated with testrails.  Because of the restrictions around the testrail api, the framework was designed to collate test result in bulk and upload them all at once when the test run is complete.

To do so, I've created a BaseTest class that provides a variable id that each test method can set itself to match a corresponding test case in test rails.  Once the test method assigns this variable, we pack it in to the result object:

```
public abstract class BaseTest {

protected static final ThreadLocal<Integer> testrailIds = new ThreadLocal();
protected int testRailCaseId = -1;

//TODO: set down a clear and strong process for handling environment/domain.  Once that is in place, report it
// loudly so it is clear where the tests ran
protected String baseUrl = "";
protected static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BaseTest.class);

/**
 * records the case ID stored at the individual test level inside the result set for the
 * test so that we can access it later when reporting our results
 * @param result the result context object
 */
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
    if(testRailCaseId == -1) {
        LOG.warn("NO CASE ID HAS BEEN SET FOR THIS TEST");
    }
    result.setAttribute("case_id", testrailIds.get());
}
```

Once all tests have executed we build a request object in the afterSuite method and pipe both the test cases and test results to testrail.

```
for(ISuiteResult suiteResult: suite.getResults().values()) {
            ctx = suiteResult.getTestContext();

            for (ITestResult result : ctx.getPassedTests().getAllResults()) {
                cases.add((int) result.getAttribute("case_id"));
                JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
                resultJson.put("case_id", result.getAttribute("case_id"));
                resultJson.put("status_id", 1);
                payload.add(resultJson);
            }
            for (ITestResult result : ctx.getFailedTests().getAllResults()) {
                cases.add((int) result.getAttribute("case_id"));
                JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
                resultJson.put("case_id", result.getAttribute("case_id"));
                resultJson.put("status_id", 5);
                payload.add(resultJson);
            }
        }

        // get a clean instance of the api
        TestRailApi tr = new TestRailApi();

        //now dump that arraylist into a json param and add it to the test run
        tr.updateRun(runId, cases);

        //once the test run has been created, clean up again and build the results request
        tr = new TestRailApi();
        tr.addResultsForCases(runId, payload);
```

the testRailCaseId is set at the beginning of each test method with a simple assignment

```
this.testRailCaseId = 491;
or
testrailIds.set(489);
```

This worked fine until we started using multi-threading.  Now, the value of testRaidCaseId is being overwritten by parallel tests, resulting in smaller result sets than expected.

I've been attempting to manage the threads through a ThreadLocal (as seen in the code above), but have been unsuccessful so far -- values I try to set in the before method or in the tests are coming up empty in the after methods.

The test methods themselves are fine, my only struggle is with shared content being passed into them from the parent.

Anyone have any guidance for how to manage my variables across the baseTest through the test methods to ensure my various ids don't clobber each other?

Sample test case:

```
@Test
@Parameters({ "domain", "username", "password" })
public void logInAuthEmptyToken(@Optional("http://REDACTED.com") String domain, String username, String password) {
    this.testRailCaseId = 385;

    Map<String, String> loginInfo = BaseAuthTests.login(domain, username, password);
    AuthServiceApi auth = new AuthServiceApi(domain);

    auth.addAuthTokens("", loginInfo.get("arrival_key"), loginInfo.get("profile_key"));
    auth.executeLogin(400);
}
```

Comment: did you tried with Listeners https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125229/how-to-get-the-test-result-status-from-testng-selenium-in-aftermethod

Comment: Can you please clarify how are you setting the testRailID ? Is it via `this.testRailCaseId = 491;` (or) is it via `testrailIds.set(489);` ? Does it fail when using both ? It would be great if you could please edit your question and add a sample `@Test` method as well for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I attempted to set the testrailID with both methods above.  Will edit and add a sample test case shortly.